# ValueError("Expected: ASCII-armored PGP data") when using pgp_key.from_blob(key_string)

Tags: python, encryption, openpgp

I am getting ValueError("Expected: ASCII-armored PGP data") when using pgp_key.from_blob(key_string) when trying to parse the key.

```
pgp_key = pgpy.PGPKey()
key = pgp_key.from_blob(key_string);
```

I tried using parse method as well but getting the same error.

Comment: The posted snippet for the key import seems to be OK, s. [PGPy documentation](https://pgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#loading-keys-individually). Therefore it is probably the key. [`from_blob()`](https://pgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=from_blob#pgpy.PGPKey.from_blob) reads a binary or ASCII armored key. ASCII armor is a binary-to-text-encoding in the context of PGP, s. e.g. [here](https://blog.programster.org/key-file-formats). Possibly your key is incomplete or corrupted, e.g. I can reproduce the error if the header is missing.

Comment: Thank you @Topaco There was a problem with encoding. I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by:

1. With your key as a file, run `base64 /path/to/file_name new_encoded_file_name`
2. Put your encoded key in your desired place (AWS Secrets Manager in my case)
3. Within your program, add the following line **BEFORE** getting your pgp key:

```
key_string = base64.decode(key_string)
```

4. Now `key = pgp_key.from_blob(key_string)` will no longer throw an error as the decoded string will be an ASCII-armored bytearray.